# How to write a call back function for ignore in shutil.copytree

Tags: python, file-copying, shutil

I am relatively new to python. I am trying to copy a directory to another directory maintaining the structure.

I am using

```
    shutil.copytree(src, dst, symlinks=False, ignore=None, 
    copy_function=copy2, ignore_dangling_symlinks=False)
```

I am trying to write a call back function for ignore.

My aim is to take a list of files in a list , and copy only those files,ignoring the rest. How do we pass a list into the call back function?

I wrote a simple call back function , but I get some error when I try to run the copyTree function

```
   def abc(src,names):
    print(src)
    print(names)



    Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<pyshell#23>", line 1, in <module>
shutil.copytree('D:\Mytest','D:\PythonTestDest3',symlinks=False,ignore=abc)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\shutil.py", line 204, in copytree
if name in ignored_names:
  TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The return of the ignore function needs to be a list of directories and files to ignore.  You aren't returning anything, which returns `None`,  so you are getting the error `TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable`.

Here's an example that will copy the folder structure and the files listed in 'copy_these':

```
import os.path

copy_these = ['a.txt', 'b.txt', 'c.txt']

def ignore_most(folder, files):

    ignore_list = []
    for file in files:
       full_path = os.path.join(folder, file)
       if not os.path.isdir(full_path):
           if file not in copy_these:
               ignore_list.append(file)
    return ignore_list
```

Comment: You mean `return [f for f in files if not is_dir(os.path.join(folder, f)) and f not in copy_these]`.

Comment: Nice list comprehension.  But, since the asker said he's new to Python, a more verbose style might be easier to understand and adapt.

Answer (score 6):

The [shutil](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html) module provides a [`ignore_patterns`](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html#shutil.ignore_patterns) function.

> This factory function creates a function that can be used as a callable for copytree()‘s ignore argument, ignoring files and directories that match one of the glob-style patterns provided.

The module page shows [a couple of examples](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html#copytree-example) as well.

Comment: This works perfectly if you are try to ignore a file type (which is what I was looking for).

Answer (score 0):

The ignore callback function should return a list of names relative to the 'src' directory that should not be copied.

Your example callback returns nothing (ie. None). Then copytree, expecting a list, tries to iterate over it. Since it can't, you get that exception.

Answer (score 0):

> If *ignore* is given, it must be a callable that will receive as its arguments the directory being visited ... and a list of its contents ... The callable must return a sequence of directory and file names relative to the current directory ...; these names will then be ignored in the copy process.

([docs](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html#shutil.copytree))

> My aim is to take a list of files in a list

Try an anonymous function (`lambda`) and a list comprehension:

```
copytree(src, dest,
         ignore=lambda d, files: [f for f in files
                                    if f not in files_to_copy
                                    and not is_dir(os.path.join(d, f))])
```

Note that the `lambda` function gets the basenames of the files and directories, not their full paths; kudos @jwhitlock's for the directory handling.