# The Ignore callback for python shutil.copytree() does not accept full path

Tags: python, shutil, copytree

I'd like to specify full paths to ignorable files and directories when calling shutil.copytree(). Something like

```
def my_ignore(dir, files):

    # return ["exclude.file"] # working

    return ["/full_path_to/exclude.file"] # Not working

shutil.copytree(src, dest, ignore=my_ignore)
```

After this, the excluded file is still there unless I return simply the filename instead of full path. The thing is I really want to set up a particular file instead of all matching filenames under different directories.

I referred to a number of questions here, such as:
[How to write a call back function for ignore in shutil.copytree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7012686/how-to-write-a-call-back-function-for-ignore-in-shutil-copytree)

[Filter directory when using shutil.copytree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7842044/filter-directory-when-using-shutil-copytree)

But none of the answers work. It looks like the ignore hook can only return a glob-style and any constructed full path will not work.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ignore` indeed *must* return just the filenames that are ignored. However, the function is called for each directory `shutil.copytree()` visits; you get to ignore files *per directory*.

If you have a full path to a file you need to ignore, then match against the first parameter passed to your `ignore` function; it is the full path to that directory:

```
def my_ignore(dir, files):
    if dir == '/full_path_to':
        return {"exclude.file"}
```

I return a set here; set membership testing is faster than with a list.

If you have a predefined set of paths to ignore, parse those out into a dictionary; keys are the directory path, values sets of filenames in that path:

```
from collections import defaultdict

to_ignore = defaultdict(set)
for path in ignored_paths:
    dirname, filename = os.path.split(path)
    to_ignore[dirname].add(filename)

def my_ignore(src, files):
    return to_ignore.get(src, set())
```

Comment: Membership testing in a set isn't faster than with a list when there's only one item.  :-)

Comment: @kindall: I doubt this is limited to just one filename at a time though.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Is ignored_paths a list of paths? I tried your code and got an error:   File "/HelloCopytree.py", line 28, in my_ignore2
    return to_ignore.get(folder, set())
TypeError: get() takes no keyword arguments

Comment: My bad: I put default=set() as a keyword arg there. Your code works fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's not magic. `copytree()` copies the contents of one directory at a time and it specifically looks for *filenames* in the ignore list you return. A full path is never the name of a file, so it is never matched.

However, the `dir` parameter will help you do what you want:

```
def my_ignore(dir, files):
    if dir == "/full/path/to":
        return ["exclude.file"]
    else:
        return []
```